# RUBY::URI When provided with host alone., eg, URI.extract("www.google.com") ... should consider it as URL

Tags: ruby, uri

When i am passing some text like "http://google.com" to URI,

```
urls = URI.extract('http://google.com', ['http', 'https'])
# ['http://google.com']
```

i get back the proper URL. My problem here is, even if i pass without a domain but with host, still it needs to be a link and not text..

For example

```
urls = URI.extract('www.google.com', ['http', 'https'])
# ['']
```

I am not sure if URI.extract will work for my case.

Please suggest if any workaround for URI.extract or any other better / clean way to get this done.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the URl as below:

```
url=URI.parse("http://www.google.com")
```

learn more on [ruby-doc.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i'll not be getting http://... from the frontend.. It will be just "www.google.com".. Even i can't append http:// in front of it, before validating if its a proper URL..

Comment: Yes.. It will consider any string, even just 'google' give as a url. For me, from the user input (Includes string + url + ..), i need to add href to links alone for preview. where i can get things done with ['http', 'https', 'ftp', 'mailto'].. But for 'www' (FOR HOST) it was not working...

Comment: I couldn't get your question quite well, can you explain what exactly you want to do, and where you get the URl at first?